Azure Devops create a pipeline with multiple configurations
Is there a way to create a new pipeline that will hold multiple configurations and ability to choose which one of them to run?
I'll give an example.
lets say I have 2 repositories in my project.
I would like to have a pipeline that clone the 2 repos and run a bat/csh file that builds an exe with some given parameters.
now lets say I have multiple release branches of these 2 repositories and I would like the pipeline to save all multiple default branches of these repos and their parameters in a configuration file to be used by the pipeline.
so if I need to deliver a hotfix based on one of the branches, all parameters used to run this pipeline in the past are set and I can modify whatever parameter I need for the hot fix (e.g. branch name of one of the repos).
same as repos there could be more parameters of the pipeline or even different number of repos per release build.
is such pipeline configuration possible in Azure DevOps?
Thanks,
David
I try to google it but with no success

Firstly, question: what problem you are trying to solve? Secondly, can you provide some examples? Or visual?


I would like to have a pipeline that clone the 2 repos

To clone multiple repositories in your pipeline, you can use the repository resource in your yaml. You can refer this Check out multiple repositories in your pipeline for more details.

create a new pipeline that will hold multiple configurations and ability to choose which one of them to run

You can use the concept of parameters in your pipeline YAML file to hold multiple configurations and choose which one to run.
The following is an example yaml. I have two repos nextjs-starter and testrepo. The pipeline is in the testrepo. The repos have the main and feature branches.
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: RepoB 
    name: projectname/nextjs-starter
    ref: main
    type: git

parameters:
- name: repoName
  displayName: Repo Name
  type: string
  default: testrepo
  values:
  - testrepo
  - nextjs-starter
- name: branchName
  displayName: Branch Name
  type: string
  default: main
  values:
  - main
  - feature

jobs:
- job: build
  displayName: build
  steps:
  - checkout: self   
  - checkout: RepoB
  - script: |
      cd "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)//${{ parameters.repoName }}"
      git status
      git checkout ${{ parameters.branchName }}
      dir
      echo building $(Build.BuildNumber) with the   ${{ parameters.branchName }} branch of ${{ parameters.repoName }} 
      echo do the build here

Result:
You can choose to build the pipeline with the repo and the branch you need.


